# Dropdowns in navigation are not hiding properly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented simple dropdown navigation using . I want to show dropdown when user hovers over mat-menu and hide it on leave.

So I used (mouseenter) and (mouseleave) to achieve that. It hides when I go down with cursor, but when I hover mat-menu to the right, instead of going down, dropdown doesn't hide.

I've made a gif to show what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Lqk.jpg

And here is stackblitz of this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahhw2s-spkuxw?file=app%2Fmenu-overview-example.html

What should I change my code to close current menu on leave to next buttons?

Comment: Why do you have to use `angular-material` for this? Can't you simply use bootstrap or something? very easy with it.